# which is better : F1-score of 'N' in imbalanced data or 'N+3' in balanced data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, feature-selection, machine-learning-model

I have a dataset with 4712 records. Label 1 is 1558(33%) and Label 0 is 3154 (67%)

a)  Currently when I run the model and analysis as is (without sampling techniques), I get an `F1-score` of `71-77`. I chose `F1-score` and `AUC score` as the metric as my dataset is imbalanced. (Atleast that's what I felt looking at class proportion). My AUC also ranges between 80-83 for tree based models. Screenshot of models with imbalanced data is given below

[image]

b) When I under-sample the majority class, I get all the metrics like `F1-score`/`accuracy`/`AUC` above `80` but less than 85

screenshot below

[image]

Now I am not sure which one should I consider? I know it's all about trade-offs.

**My objective is to avoid/minimize the misclassifications**

Based on your experience in ML projects, what would you guys suggest?

Can someone enlighten me with some reasons why to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second.**

why? you said you objective is to minimize misclassifications which equates to maximizing
F1 score, and you achieve that in inbalaced situations when you down-sample the majority class (one approach to maximize)

**Potential Pitfall:**

It could be that you just got rid of of some important infomration in the majority class and you are over-fitting on what is left.
In some cases 1500 datasamples would suffice, but I it could be that it doesn not have enough information. I would rather advise to upsample the smaller class, for example using [ADASYN, SMOTe , knnSMOT](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN.html)E etc...
Only you can answer this question, by knowing some meta-information about your dataset, quality rules, are you expecting huge covariate-shift, is the dropped data really that different in distribution, etc...

Then do the analysis. If there is one thing you should always ask for is diverse and informative dataset, and **more data will (almost) always beat better algorithm.**

Comment: I tried with `SMOTE` but the result looks more or less the same as option a) where the `F1-score` is between 72-77. Even after upsampling using `SMOTE`, I don't see much difference in metric

Comment: Machine learning is SOFT science, with weakish mathematical theory. You do not have definitive answers on all questions, but best guesses.